# Why Inserting User must happen in a future method?

Tags: apex, future

I found this statement `"Inserting a user with a non-null role must be done in a separate thread from DML operations on other sObjects"` "[here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_scheduler.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fapex_scheduler.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)" and below is the code:

```
    public class MixedDMLFuture {
    public static void useFutureMethod() {
        // First DML operation
        Account a = new Account(Name='Acme');
        insert a;

        // This next operation (insert a user with a role) 
        // can't be mixed with the previous insert unless 
        // it is within a future method. 
        // Call future method to insert a user with a role.
        Util.insertUserWithRole(
            'mruiz@awcomputing.com', 'mruiz', 
            'mruiz@awcomputing.com', 'Ruiz');        
    }
}
```

Could someone please clarify on why we can't insert a user just after adding account and why it needs to be done in a future method??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inserting a user with a role (or changing a user's role) will cause a sharing calculation for that user, which is a (potentially) expensive operation. While I've never specifically tried inserting a user in a trigger, I would imagine that Salesforce.com would want to prevent this type of expensive recalculation during time-sensitive transactions, such as when an account is being created or, more importantly, updated. Previously, it wasn't even possible to insert users at all in a trigger, as you'd receive a "mixed DML" error, but that does seem to have been relaxed in the past few releases or so. Regardless, I'd be hesitant to modify any Setup object within a trigger. Doing so asynchronously seems like a Good Idea.

Comment: Also note that adding Users consumes Licenses. If you add Users in a Trigger that approach will not scale for many enterprises. You would run out of licenses and your trigger would throw an exception. Sfdcfox is right, you should avoid setup objects in triggers.